# Why Firefox randomly kills HTTPS requests?

Tags: debugging, firefox, https

See:

Here are images are downloaded good:

https://polishwords.com.pl/dev/testAbort2.php

And here:

https://polishwords.com.pl/dev/testAbort.php

I get them in Firefox with HTTPS and randomly one of them is Aborted and does not display correctly.

In logs on server it looks like this:

[22/Mar/2013:23:29:11 +0100] "GET /images/mukonczeniestudiow.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6705 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"

And when the file is loaded ok:

[22/Mar/2013:23:30:41 +0100] "GET /images/mukonczeniestudiow.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6907 "https://polishwords.com.pl/dev/testAbort.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"

What can be the cause of this problem?
In Chrome and in Opera it seems to work fine. I have latest Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something on server blocking several queries